# How to detect if "Find my device" is ON programmatically?

Tags: android

I need to change the availability of functionalities based on the `Find my device` setting for security purpose, but I couldn't find the way to get the value programmatically. 
Does anybody know how to?

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**

FYI, I already checked [Settings.Global](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html), [Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) and [Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html), but no luck :'(

Comment: AFAIK, "find my device" is a Google thing, not an Android thing, and so it would not be in the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh yes, it's a good point, thanks! I'll search the way to get the value from maybe user's Google Account or somewhere like that!